# How to jump words in text editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, coderush

I used to be able to hold down the Ctrl key and press arrows to jump over words in a text for navigation or selection of text. I even had it configured that it would respect camelhumps. However after a new installation of Visual Studio these settings have been lost. I've also installed CodeRush, but haven't found anything like these features in there.

Edit versions added:
CodeRush v20.1.3, trial
Visual Studio 2019 16.4.6

Comment: Can I ask which versions of Visual Studio and CodeRush do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this function on the ALT key. In order to make it work on the CTRL key, that key had to be the only key with the function. If I made it an alternative key, the text editor would just lose focus when pressing CTRL+LEFT.